# Camera2 API Camera Manager Suspicious Cast

Tags: java, android

While trying to use the Camera manger class for a school project, I get the error: Suspicious cast to CameraManager for a CAMERA_SERVICE: Expected CameraManager.
The line where the error occured was: 
`CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);`

Comment: @Andrea That was the problem, thanks a lot. I feel like an idiot now

Comment: No need at all, it's a common problem :) I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you have a custom class, called `CameraManager`, and you are implicitly casting to that one instead than Android original one.